# Node.js promise .then() not sequence

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

it's run .then() number2 before number1 done.
P.S. getConnectIn() is promise

```js
function query(sql){
            var data = [555,555];
            getConnectIn()
               .then((check_connect)=>{   //then 1
                 if(check_connect){
                   connector.query(sql,function(err,result,fields){
                            data = result;
                      });
                  setTimeout(()=>{console.log("data before>",data);},1000);
                 }
              })
              .then(()=>{  //then 2
                console.log("data after>",data);
              })
              .catch((err)=>{console.log("error >",err)})
 }
```

[display picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fnu2C.png)

Comment: are you getting an error. what are you trying to achieve. try and put some additional details.

Comment: `setTimeout(()=>{console.log("data before>",data);},1000);` never pauses execution, regardless of where it is (inside a promise, not inside a promise, an async function etc)... you need to return a promise that resolves after 1 second if you want to wait

Comment: try `return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(()=>{console.log("data before>",data);, resolve()},1000));`

Comment: also ... using timeout to wait for asynchronous data is not how you do it

Comment: how to do it properly - https://pastebin.com/qCWwCgUW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `then` in wrong way. In first `then` handler method you are not returning anything which is why JS engine will continue running next `then` in the chain. Update your code to:

```js
function query(sql) {
  var data = [555, 555];
  getConnectIn()
    .then((check_connect) => { //then 1
      if (check_connect) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          connector.query(sql, function(err, result, fields) {
            If (err) { 
              reject(err);
            } else {
              resolve(result);
            }
          });
        });
      }
    })
    .then(result => { //then 2
      // now you can access result here!
      console.log("data after>", data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("error >", err)
    })
}
```

Take a look at [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining) to learn more about promise chaining.

Comment: i'm newbie of Stackoverflow,and i don'n know how to use it,but i want to activate your comment.

Comment: Awesome could you please accept it as an answer in that case. You can click on checkbox sign under updown arrows on my answer to mark it.

Comment: hey mr.Dipen I have a new problem,i want to return data to query function but it be "Promise { <pending> }" pls help me

Comment: You have to wait until promise is resolve but you can still do chaining. Do you mind sharing your code?

Answer (score 0):

Basically 1 then call first but you call async method again (connector.query) which takes time and control pass to next call and then setTimeout pass execution process to next , either return new promise when call setTimeout or Use second then after your async connector.query() method like this. here you don't need timeout also

```
function query(sql){
                var data = [555,555];
                getConnectIn()
                   .then((check_connect)=>{   //then 1
                     if(check_connect){
                       connector.query(sql,function(err,result,fields){
                               // data = result;
                          }).then((rslt)=>{  //then 2
                    console.log("data after>",rslt);
                        })
                  .catch((err)=>{console.log("error >",err)}
                     }
                  });
     }
```